# Apache server on Macos Monterey not accepting external public IP connections... why?

Tags: apache-2.4, mac-osx, nat, port-forwarding, wireshark

I am using MacOS Monterey 12.4 and have configured an Apache 2.4 server with virtual hosts that listen to all interfaces (`0.0.0.0:80`) on my host. I have tested my private ip (`192.168.1.2`), external-facing ip, as well as localhost on chrome and my webpage shows up as expected.

However, when I asked my colleague to enter my public IP address on a web browser to load up Apache's webpage, he sees the "`[mypublicip] took too long to respond.`" message. Here's what I have done to diagnose this issue so far:

1. Enabled Port Forwarding on my ISP's router (80 -> 80) with TCP enabled
2. Temporarily disabled firewall
3. Temporarily disabled Antivirus software
4. Verify that Port Forwarding works by capturing the traffic sent by my colleague with Wireshark. I see his public IP attempting to establish a TCP connection (`[SYN]`) with my private IP, `192.168.1.2` on port 80. My host never responds to the connection which leads to many `[TCP Retransmission] [TCP Port numbers reused]` on his end.
5. Checked that port 80 is enabled with `nmap localhost`

I am not sure why the complete TCP connection isn't established after doing all the steps above and am currently baffled. In particular, why is my host not responding to the TCP [SYN] message? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've tagged this question with `wireshark`. Have you used `wireshark` to verify whether or not the request is making it to your Apache server?

Comment: @larsks When I entered my router's public IP in chrome, I get directed to the Apache webpage and is able to capture the complete TCP connection as well as the HTTP responses. When my colleague, who's in a remote network, typed my public IP, I am only able to see what was described in step 4 above. I don't see any HTTP responses from Apache via Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is an issue with MacOS's firewall, even after I updated to Ventura. The firewall needs to be turned off and I must restart my Mac in order for the firewall changes to take effect. That's the only way I am able to access my site.